# How to assign value type byte array in java to a button

Tags: java, algorithm, encryption, netbeans

I’m trying to develop a system that will ask the user to enter a text in JTextBox (plainText) then it will click on key JButton (key_128) then it will encrypt the user text and show the output in another JTextButton. But when I try to assign the value to the Key it gives error where.    BinaryCodec() saying cannot find symbol. The code is this- error in line 2

```
byte[] plain = plaintext.getText().getBytes();
byte[] K = new BinaryCodec().toByteArray(“0011000100110011100000001010”);
byte[] encrypted = encrypt(plain, K);
String a = new String(encrypted);
encryptedtext.setText(a);
```

Comment: Can you post your import statements that you use for this code?

Comment: Try adding this import to the top of your code file `import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.*`

Comment: @SteelToe my important list are import java.util.AreayList; important javax.swing.table.DefaultTablModel; import javax.crypto.Cipher; and i just added the one you told me but it gives error under org. Besides the hints didn’t give me to import any library :(

Comment: That means you need to add the apache commons library to your project. Are you using maven or gradle as your build engine?

Comment: @SteelToe I don’t know Whats im using i tried google it. But i use netbeans

Comment: You have to add the library to your project then. The library can be downloaded here https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-codec/download_codec.cgi then add the import statement that i wrote above and you should be good

Comment: Ok thank you so much, I really appreciate it! I will download it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that you are missing the import statement for the `BinaryCodec` class and the apache codec library that contains it.

So to solve:

First: Add the apache codec library to your project, this can be done either through a build tool like gradle or maven, or manually from here https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-codec/download_codec.cgi

Second: Add this line to the top of the class `import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.*`

Comment: When I download it. Should i put the library somewhere in SDK files?